# Lookup column with writeback

Tags: sharepoint, moss, lookup

Has anyone ever made a sharepoint lookup column that allows fill inn choices and does writeback to the list it does lookup from? what would it take to make such a column?

If a 3.rd party solution is arround that would be realy great to :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom field type:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997448/how-to-manage-column-based-access-control-in-sharepoint-lists/997773#997773

Answer (score 0):

On a project i've worked on we used a TagControl FieldType, with an entry field and a multiple select field. A user could enter a new Tag or select an existing one. If you are interested, i could send you the code.