# SharePoint Custom Fields In List View

Tags: sharepoint

I've got a requirement to hold a DateTime value in a SharePoint field but to customise the display in a list view so that it shows as a mmmm string. The underlying value must remain as the DateTime so the sort is chronological rather than alphabetical.

So I think that a Custom Field is the way to go, I'll also get some added benefit in restricting the user interface to a month picker so even if there is another solution I'll likely go down this route to get that.

I've read that I can apply custom templates to the new, edit and display actions but I can't seem to find anything saying how to alter the list view (display patterns doesn't seem to be enough).

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using a bit of an ugly series of `<IfSubString`> within the RenderPattern...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is what you are looking for but I have used a solution with a custom fieldcontrol that overrides RenderFieldForDisplay like:

```
protected override void  RenderFieldForDisplay(HtmlTextWriter output)
```

This is a similar post:

[How to manage column based access control in Sharepoint lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997448/how-to-manage-column-based-access-control-in-sharepoint-lists/997773#997773)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help, I need to actually alter the way the value is rendered in the list mode. I've become convinced that the custom field control isn't called at all for the list mode.