# How do you link Sharepoint Lists across different sites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have googled this and seem to only be able to find the same Tutorial [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx) or variations thereof.  I have two lists.  Each one is on a different site.  I need to make a list/view joining these two lists.  One site contains basic employee data, (such as department) and the other site contains details about that department that we need to show on a high level overview of employee data.

It's sharepoint 2007, two sites, same collection

Comment: Do you mean between lists across site-collections or between lists in sites in the same site collection?

Comment: Colin's question is rather important to your answer as most 3rd party tools only provide the ability to join across lists on sites within a single site collection.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed an important question.

They are different sites in the same site collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this [tutorial](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/link-two-lists-and-display-the-data-using-the-sharepoint-data-view.aspx).

He mentions "Please note: If your lists are on another site collection you will have to use the Connect to another library... link"  and he includes a screenshot.

Comment: thanks!  I bet I just missed that link in the other tutorial.  This was the tip I needed.

Comment: The updated link is [here](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/link-two-lists-and-display-the-data-using-the-sharepoint-data-view.aspx).

Comment: Updated link is also dead.

Answer (score 0):

Aonther way to go is to roll your own field type and make it similar to a lookup field but instead make it go fetch data from a list in a different sitecollection. I don´t have ready example of something like this but this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997448/how-to-manage-column-based-access-control-in-sharepoint-lists/997773#997773) atleast explains how to go about constructing a custom field type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Sahil Malil's technique](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-10-Performing_joins_between_SharePoint_lists.aspx). However this is much the same as the [link to Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA100991441033.aspx) that you've already given. Why doesn't this do what you need?

Comment: Because I need to connect lists from multiple different sites.  In SPD, using his technique, you are only given the option to connect to lists in the site you are currently connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple good places that have worked for me.

[Connect to Another Library in SharePoint Designer 2010](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/cizi/archive/2010/08/01/connect-to-another-library-in-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx)

[Displaying a SharePoint List from Another Team Site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93558/Displaying-a-SharePoint-List-from-another-team-sit)